# Nice way to pass parameters to PDO

Tags: php, sql, parameters, variadic-functions

Positional parameters become a nightmare when dealing with more than 3 or 4 parameters. Named parameters are verbose. I'm thinking of doing this:

```
query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ", $username, " AND password = ", $password)
```

With dynamic parameters (using `func_get_args()`), every second one being transformed into a positional parameter.

I've never seen this before and wanted to know if anyone has done this before and why/why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a clever idea. The only problem I see is how to distinguish between SQL and passed-in variables. Unless you make an assumption that every second arg is a variable. I just think that assumption is fragile, and obfuscates things more than makes them clear.

Better way would probably be to use interpolation:

```
query("SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE id = #{id}",  array("id" => "23"));
```

Then write logic to interpolate these.

Comment: Interpolation comes back to named attributes. You can already achieve it passing a second param to the execute() function.

Comment: The only way I see to do original is to have class SQLParameter wrapping anything that has to be escaped.

    query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ", new SQLParameter($username), " AND ..."); # etc

But this isn't making it much less verbose. PHP has no good syntax to make this simpler.

Comment: OK maybe my example was a little misleading, I'm talking about big SQL statements like imagine if you had to do that with 10 parameters: with named parameters/interpolation as above you'd end up writing a big array literal and positional parameters would be horrendously confusing.

Comment: Whatever method you use, after 10 parameters things start to look a bit messy, even with direct SQL.

Answer (score 4):

Named parameters don't have to be verbose, at least not compared to positional parameters. You could use shortened versions that are still obvious:

```
$st = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :u AND password = :p');
$st->bindValue(':u', $username);
$st->bindValue(':p', $password);
$st->execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think positional parameters are so bad... this is my favorite method:

```
function mysql_safe_string($value) {
    if(is_numeric($value))      return $value;
    elseif(empty($value))       return 'NULL';
    elseif(is_string($value))   return "'".mysql_real_escape_string($value)."'";
    elseif(is_array($value))    return implode(',',array_map('mysql_safe_string',$value));
}

function mysql_safe_query($format) {
    $args = array_slice(func_get_args(),1);
    $args = array_map('mysql_safe_string',$args);
    $query = vsprintf($format,$args);
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if($result === false) echo '<div class="mysql-error"><strong>Error: </strong>',mysql_error(),'<br/><strong>Query: </strong>',$query,'</div>';
    return $result;
}

// example
$result = mysql_safe_query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=%s', $username);
```

Comment: Those aren't positional parameters in a prepared query. That's how you fake it when you don't have prepared queries.

Comment: Oh. I thought 'positional' meant like the first `%s` refers to the first argument, and so forth...

Comment: You could make the case that you're using positional parameters. The main point of my comment is that you're not using prepared queries, thus not addressing OP's question.